# How to double layer GAT

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I try to double layer GAT for this code:

```
class AntispoofModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device="cpu", **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        resnet = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)
        self.resnet = nn.Sequential(*[i for i in list(resnet.children())[:-2]]).to(device)
        for ch in self.resnet.children():
            for param in ch.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False
        self.gat = GAT(**kwargs).to(device)
        self.device = device
        self.adj = torch.tensor(grid_to_graph(3, 3, return_as=np.ndarray)).to(device)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.resnet(x.to(self.device))
        x = nn.functional.avg_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = x.view(-1, 9, 512)
        #adj = torch.stack([self.adj for i in range(x.shape[0])]).to(self.device)
        x = self.gat(x, self.adj)
        return torch.sigmoid(x)
```

As I understand I just need to add line `x = self.gat(x, self.adj)` somewhere else. But I don't understand where (start/middle/end).
Can someone help, please?

Comment: Are you referring to [this `GAT`](https://github.com/gordicaleksa/pytorch-GAT/blob/main/models/definitions/GAT.py)?

Comment: This GAT [link](https://github.com/Diego999/pyGAT)

Comment: @WakemeUpNow What about your GAT? I just use different implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class AntispoofModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device="cpu", **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        resnet = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)
        self.resnet = nn.Sequential(*[i for i in list(resnet.children())[:-2]]).to(device)
        for ch in self.resnet.children():
            for param in ch.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False
        self.gat1 = GAT(**kwargs).to(device)
        self.gat2 = GAT(**kwargs).to(device)
        self.device = device
        self.adj = torch.tensor(grid_to_graph(3, 3, return_as=np.ndarray)).to(device)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.resnet(x.to(self.device))
        x = nn.functional.avg_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = x.view(-1, 9, 512)
        x = self.gat1(x, self.adj)
        x = self.gat2(x, self.adj)
        return torch.sigmoid(x)
```

Comment: UPD: I added the second layer GAT. But now I have ```mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x1 and 512x64)```. I know that I need to have ```(m x n) with (n x p)```
I tried to change this parametrs but it doesn't give result:

Comment: ```preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

torch.manual_seed(42)
kwargs = {"nfeat":512, "nhid":64, "nclass":1, "nheads":9, "dropout":0.6, "alpha":0.01}

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)```